# Silex SessionLogoutHandler

Tags: session, symfony, silex, invalidation

In Symfony it's possible to avoid session destroying on logout by adding `invalidate_session: false` in your `security.yml` file.

This is sadly not working in Silex. In Silex there is an EventListener `SessionLogoutHandler` which calls:

```
public function logout(Request $request, Response $response, TokenInterface $token)
{
    $request->getSession()->invalidate();
}
```

This EventListener will be added in `SecurityServiceProvider`:

`$listener->addHandler(new SessionLogoutHandler());`

I have found no possibility to not add or to remove this handler... or am I missing something?

Thanks for the answers.

**[UPDATE]**

Review my pull request at https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/pull/916

Answer (score 0):

As a short-term solution you can override `$app['security.authentication_listener.logout._proto']` with the very same code it has by default, except registering the event listener you're having the problem with.

For a long-term solution (and if you come up with a way that's viable) you can fork silex on github, add a way to optionally toggle it off, then send a pull request so others benefit from your work as well :)

Comment: I've done the long-term solution ;-) Review my pull request at https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/pull/916